# AS3 - Unable to capture button click when using Mouse Move listener

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

In my first AS3 project (not used Flash since AS1) I need to use a custom movie clip as a cursor and detect clicking on a button. Using the code below, the custom cursor works as expected, but I am unable to capture clicking on the button.

If I comment out the first line, the trace for clicking works as expected. I have tried changing the order of the event listeners, applying the follow to the button rather than the stage, but cannot get both to work together.

Any advice as to where I'm going wrong ould be appreciated.

```
stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_MOVE,follow);
start_button.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, playPhrase);

function playPhrase(event:MouseEvent) {
    trace("Click received");
};

function follow(event:MouseEvent) {
    cursor.x = mouseX;
    cursor.y = mouseY;
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like that's because you always click on the cursor object as it always positioned right under mouse cursor. Make it "transparent" for mouse clicks:

```
cursor.mouseEnabled = false;
```

And if it's a DisplayObjectContainer then also:

`cursor.mouseChildren = false;`